# Manipulate an LDAP string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have an LDAP path and I only want the OU's from it. How can I manipulate it to get the OU's??

e.g.

```
LDAP://company.com/OU=MyOU,DC=MyCompany,DC=com
```

to be show as `MyOU`

```
LDAP://company.com/OU=MyOU1,OU=MyOU2,DC=MyCompany,DC=com
```

to be shown as `MyOU1/MyOU2`

```
LDAP://company.com/OU=MyOU1,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU3,DC=MyCompany,DC=com
```

to be shown as `MyOU1/MyOU2/MyOU3`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
string str = "LDAP://company.com/OU=MyOU1,OU=MyOU2,OU=MyOU3,DC=MyCompany,DC=com";
Regex regex = new Regex("OU=\\w+");
var result = regex.Matches(str);
var strList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    strList.Add(item.ToString().Remove(0,3));
 }
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/",strList));
```

Comment: i get an error on the last line: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'?? thanks

Comment: Console.WriteLine(string.Join("/",strList.ToArray()))

Comment: this is one more problem if the string is OU=mydomain control,DC... then it only returns mydomain and not control.. whereas i want mydomain control